# "unrecognized arguments" error while executing a Dataflow job with gcloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have created a job in Dataflow UI and it works fine. Now I want to automate it from the command line with a small bash script:

```
#GLOBAL VARIABLES
export PROJECT="cf-businessintelligence"
export GCS_LOCATION="gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Jdbc_to_BigQuery"
export MAX_WORKERS="15"
export NETWORK="businessintelligence"
export REGION_ID="us-central1"
export STAGING_LOCATION="gs://dataflow_temporary_directory/temp_dir"
export SUBNETWORK="bidw-dataflow-usc1"
export WORKER_MACHINE_TYPE="n1-standard-96"
export ZONE="us-central1-a"
export JOBNAME="test"

#COMMAND
gcloud dataflow jobs run $JOBNAME --project=$PROJECT --gcs-location=$GCS_LOCATION \
--max-workers=$MAX_WORKERS \
--network=$NETWORK \
--parameters ^:^query="select current_date":connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://mysqldbhost:3306/bidw":user="xyz",password="abc":driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver":driverJars="gs://jdbc_drivers/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar":outputTable="cf-businessintelligence:bidw.mytest":tempLocation="gs://dataflow_temporary_directory/tmp" \
--region=$REGION_ID \
--staging-location=$STAGING_LOCATION \
--subnetwork=$SUBNETWORK \
--worker-machine-type=$WORKER_MACHINE_TYPE \
--zone=$ZONE
```

When I run it, it fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.jobs.run) unrecognized arguments:
  --network=businessintelligence
```

Following the instructions in `gcloud topic escaping` , I believe I correctly escaped my parameters so I am really confused. Why is failing on the NETWORK parameter?

Comment: have you tried providing only the subnetwork? I am thinking that network is not supported on templates (which is likely a bug)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting help for your command, to see which options are currently accepted by it:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run --help
```

For me, this displays a number of options, but not the `--network` option.

---

I then checked the `beta` channel:

```
gcloud beta dataflow jobs run --help
```

And it **does** display the `--network` option. So you'll want to launch your job with `gcloud beta dataflow...`.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `network` and `subnetwork` arguments need to be the complete URL.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#example_network_and_subnetwork_specifications

Example for the `subnetwork` flag:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/HOST_PROJECT_ID/regions/REGION_NAME/subnetworks/SUBNETWORK_NAME
```